# Why does this HashMap.get return a null?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to create a `Hashmap` to perform a lookup for me.  However when I run this test code, the output is null.  I think it has to due with the nature of how the keys are being stored, but Im not positive.  Maybe it's a similar quirk like how the `var1 == var2` are not equals unless they point to the same Object in memory, instead you have to use the `var1.equals(var2)`?

There are two classes to test this.

**TestCard.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestCard {

     // HashMap for SpecialK Lookup
    private static HashMap<Card, Integer> specialKLookup = new HashMap<Card, Integer>();

    // Constructor
    public TestCard(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card[] cards = new Card[3];
        cards[0] = new Card((short)12, (short)0);
        cards[1] = new Card((short)0, (short)1);
        cards[2] = new Card((short)5, (short)2);

        /* Build SpecialK Lookup HashMap.
         * Ace of Spades = 0
         * Ace of Hearts = 1
         * Ace of Diamonds = 2
         * Ace of Clubs = 3
         * ...
         * Two of Clubs = 51
         */
        Integer specialKCounter = 0;
        for(int i=12;i>=0;i--){
                for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
                        specialKLookup.put(new Card((short)i, (short)j), specialKCounter++);
                }
        }

        System.out.println(specialKLookup.get(cards[0]));
    }
}
```

**Card.java**

```
public class Card{
    private short rank, suit;

    private static String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    private static String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};

    //Constructor
    public Card(short rank, short suit){
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    // Getter and Setters
    public short getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    public short getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    protected void setSuit(short suit){
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    protected void setRank(short rank){
        this.rank = rank;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class (`Card`) is missing a proper implementation of [`equals(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Without both of these defined it *will just not work*. (It compiles fine because these methods are both virtual and inherited in all objects as they are part of Object: HashMap can't enforce this at compile-time.) See the links above for the contract that is required.

Both of these methods are required to be implemented because `hashCode` determines the hash-bucket used in the HashMap implementation and `equals` is to ensure that an object is value-equals (multiple objects can have the same `hashCode`, which is why `equals` is also required). See [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for more general hash details.

If these methods are not overloaded then the implementations defined in Object are used. That is, `x.equals(y)` has near-`x == y` semantics and `hashCode` returns a stable number per contract. This effectively makes the map work like an *identity map* (when Card objects are keys): only *the exact same object* can retrieve a previously stored value -- every other get will return null, as observed.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed exactly because of this issue.

You need to define what equality means on cards, so you need to override the [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods.

If you do not, it assumes that two cards are only equal if they're the same instance. (As in the default behavior of `equals`.)

Note that, it is very important you override both `equals` and `hashCode`, as two objects that're equal *must* hash to the same value for a `HashMap` to work correctly.

For more information, see [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe it's a similar quick like how the var1 == var2 are not equals unless they point to the > same Object in memory, instead you have to use the var1.equals(var2)

Almost. As you would expect, a hash map needs a way of getting hash codes for your objects. In Java, this is provided by the [hashCode method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) which is implemented by Object, but needs to be overridden by your Card class.

*update: as pst points out, it must also reimplement equals.

Comment: It must also implement `equals`, per the contract.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the hashCode and equals methods, since this allows equality testing on two different objects, and also helps with hash map storage. Without implementing these, two objects will be seen as distinct even if their properties are the same. See http://www.jchq.net/certkey/0902certkey.htm for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Card should override `equals` and `hashCode`.
Take a look here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to override the `hashCode()` method for `Card` and make it return the same value if and only if the cards are equal - you should override `equals()` too. Because that's what the `HashMap` relies on in order to find the objects referenced by the keys; as it stands now, it's the versions of those methods inherited from `Object` that are being used, which will only match if you use the same objects as keys, whereas you're creating new, albeit 'equal', ones.

Comment: If `equals()` returns true, the `hashCode()` must be the same. If `equals()` returns false, the outcome of `hashCode()` still may be equal but also may differ. If the outcome of `hashCode()` differs, `equals()` must return false.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in that two not equals objects can have the same hash code (ie, the statement that "if and only if the cards are equal " is incorrect). Arjan sums it up correctly.

Comment: @SteveKuo so if I removed 'and only if' from what I wrote, the answer would no longer be incorrect, but your comments would cease making sense. What should I do?