# Counting class instances in a map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a shopping site, in which items can be added to a basket, each item is an instance of a class Product, and all the items are stored in a `Collection<Product>` items,

I am currently then iterating through that list and displaying each item in a table.

However I want to display a quantity value for each item instead.

I created a `Map`, and am trying to put each of my products into it.

However each Product is still listed as only existing once because each class instance is different?
How would I adjust this?

My Product class has a product ID value. Here's the code I have currently.

```
Map<Product, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Product p : items) {
    Integer i = map.get(p);
    if (i == null) {
        map.put(p, 1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(p, i+1);
    }
}
```

Having implemented hashcode and equals methods.

Trying to add the items to the map.

```
Collection<Product> items = basket.getItems();
    Map<Product, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Product p : items) {
        for (Product key : map.keySet()) {
            if (p.equals(key)) {
                map.put(key, map.get(key));
            }
            else {
                map.put(p, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you adding the two equivalent `Product`in the map ? Is it different instances, if so, are you implementing `equals` and `hashCode()` to be able to compare two distinct instance ? In the code, what is this `items` iterable ? EDIT : well no, @SeanPatrickFloyd write it before I validate ^^

Comment: I'd suggest you actually creating a CartItem class, that encapsulates the product and the quantity.

Comment: do you want this?  map.put(p, i+p.getQuantity());

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this HashMap.get return a null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078207/why-does-this-hashmap-get-return-a-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However each Product is still listed as only existing once because each class instance is different?

Yes.

`HashMap` identifies keys by using their implementation of `hashcode()` and `equals()`.

You you either use a property, which already has a proper implementation of both (as  @zsmb13 suggested) or you create implementations of `hashcode()` and `equals()` in your Product class (ATTENTION! do **not** inherit them! They must be implemented in a decent child which will not be extended itself...).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly a hashcode should return a value by hashing two values that are uniquely identifiable so if I hash the product id and it's title, every class instance that has the same product will therefore have the same hashcode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `equals` and the `hashCode` of Product Class for your hashing based operations to function properly. You need your Product class something like this

```
class Product{

    private int price;
    private String name;

    public Product(String itm, int pr){
        this.name = itm;
        this.price = pr;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        int hashcode = 0;
        hashcode = price*20;
        hashcode += name.hashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Product) {
            Product pp = (Product) obj;
            return (pp.name.equals(this.name) && pp.price == this.price);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I then use this to iterate through my collection of Product instances and add them to the map if they're equal? I'll post what I've attempted in the op.